# QuerySet doesn't render

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a QuerySet that I can see via print has items

```
<QuerySet [<Task: 1|root|test_task2>, <Task: 2|root|asdf>, <Task: 3|root|asdfafd>, <Task: 5|root|asdfasdfwe>, <Task: 6|root|asdfasdf>]>
```

which when I then try to render in template via:

```
return render(request, 'tasks.html',{'tasks:': tasks})
```

template:

```
{% for task in tasks %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ task }} <a href=/tasks/edit/{{ task.id }}>edit</a> <a href=/tasks/delete/{{ task.id }}>delete</a> <a href=/tasks/mark_done/{{ task.id }}>mark_done</a></td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
shows up as if tasks was None
<table>
```

Comment: Suggestion -- try `django-debug-toolbar`, it's saved my countless hours in debugging these kinds of things.

Answer (score 0):

Late night typo

See
{'tasks:': tasks}

should be
{'tasks': tasks}